# Cross compiling stand alone application?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, toolchain, gnu-toolchain

I am trying to cross compiling a stand alone application for arm board and most important I want to compile it without Android.mk framework.

I have following doubt :-

1- Which tool should I use like (arm-eabi or arm-linux-androideabi
            etc).

2- From where should I download library and toolchain related
            parts.

3- What are compilation flags should I include for stand alone
            compilation (completely static).

Please Comment if question is not clear also please add related information that is I missing , detailed information will be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend reading the documentation regarding the usage of build tools with the Android native development kit at [https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Standalone Toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) part of NDK covers this precisely.

First of all compiler requires to know where sysroot is located so it can find standard libraries.

```
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm
```

and then either you can do

```
export CC="$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/ \
linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.8 --sysroot=$SYSROOT"  $CC -o foo.o -c foo.c
```

and for static compilations just add `-static` to the invocation.

Advanced method is about installing a certain toolchain to a directory which then you can invoke directly without specifying the sysroot.